# Android Manifest placholder not working in intent-filter XML tag

Tags: android, android-intent, android-gradle-plugin, android-manifest, build.gradle

I am working on a project with multiple build flavors. I want each flavor to capture an intent specific to that flavor from our browser site without defining a unique manifest for each flavor so I was hoping to use manifest placeholders like so:

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="com.app.action.DO_SOMETHING" />
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <data android:scheme="somescheme" />
    <data android:host="placeholder" />
    <data android:pathPrefix=".*${flavorUri}.*" />
</intent-filter>
```

The problem is that in the intermediate output XML file, the placeholder has not been substituted, leaving the pathPrefix string as-is. I made sure that it is actually defined in the build.gradle manifestPlaceholders as well.

```
manifestPlaceholders = [applicationLabel: "@string/app_name", flavorUri: "cherry"]
```

Is there a workaround or does pathPrefix not support placeholders? [There is nothing in the documentation suggesting so](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/data-element.html#path)

Comment: Try moving the wildcard characters into the placeholder. Also, you might experiment with using the placeholder somewhere else (e.g., an `android:label`), and see if it gets expanded there.

Comment: I have tried using the wildcards in and outside of the placeholder with no change. It will get expanded if I place it in other intent attributes like the action name.

Comment: Hmmm... feels like a bug then. You might wish to create a project that demonstrates the problem, then [file an issue](http://b.android.com).